# How to replace a string while keeping sections of the original string in the replacement?

Tags: python

My code is the following. I am trying to replace a pattern in a string while trying to preserve information in the brackets

```
import re
a = ''' editor
    {
        "color" "220 30 220"
        "visgroupshown" "1"
        "visgroupautoshown" "1"
        "logicalpos" "[0 500]"
    }'''


# removes newlines and tabs. otherwise re.sub wont find pattern
a = a.replace("\n","").replace("\t","")

print(re.sub('editor{.*}','"editor":{.*}}',a))
```

what I got from print

```
"editor":{.*}}
```

what I expected

```
"editor":{"color" "220 30 220""visgroupshown" "1""visgroupautoshown" "1""logicalpos" "[0 500]"}}
```

Comment: You aren't actually using regular expressions anywhere. You're using `str.replace`, not the `re.sub` function provided by the `re` module.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
a = ''' editor
    {
        "color" "220 30 220"
        "visgroupshown" "1"
        "visgroupautoshown" "1"
        "logicalpos" "[0 500]"
    }'''


# removes newlines and tabs **and spaces**. otherwise re.sub wont find pattern
a = a.replace("\n","").replace("\t","").replace(" ","")

print(re.sub(r'editor{(.*)}',r'"editor":{\1}}',a))
```

Explanation:

- The `replace(" ","")` gets rid of space characters, otherwise your regular expression in re.sub won't match
- In Python, you need to start regular expression patterns and replacements with an `r` before the string - `r'...'` - see examples at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub
- You can't use `.*` in the replacement to refer to what the `.*` matched in the pattern. Instead, you have to wrap the `.*` with parentheses -`(.*)` - to make it a 'capture-group' and refer to it in the replacement with a *back-reference* - `\1` for the first capture-group, `\2` for the second, etc.

By the way, removing the spaces, tabs and newlines would be unnecessary if you wrote a regular expression using `\s*`, to match any kind of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need re hereTry this

```
a = ''' editor
    {
        "color" "220 30 220"
        "visgroupshown" "1"
        "visgroupautoshown" "1"
        "logicalpos" "[0 500]"
    }'''

a = a.replace("\n","").replace("\t","")
print(a)
```